# Spring @Cacheable using "unless" for Mono results

Tags: spring, caching, spring-webflux

I would like to use "unless" condition to avoid caching empty results.

my current method looks more or less similar to this:

```
@Cacheable(value = "items")
public Mono<List<Item>> getItems() {
    return getItems().cache();
}
```

getItems() in this case is a method with a WebClient call returning a Mono<List>

I would like to add a "unless" condition to this @Cacheable so nothing gets cache if the List return by getItems is empty.

All examples I can find about using #result are non webflux examples, so I'm no sure how the actual condition should looks like.

I will assume here #result is actually a Mono<List> ?

Thanks a lot
Javier

Comment: A `Mono<List>` seems weird should that just be a `Flux<Item>` instead? That being said I'm not sure if Spring Cache is useable in a reactive environment.

Comment: When using a `Flux<Item>` you might be able to use `#result.hasResult()` as an expression.

Comment: Hi M.Deinum, thanks. I agree Flux<Item> it would had been better, unfortunately this method is part of a library already being consumed by a few clients, so I'm trying to see if are any options available without having to change the method signature.

Comment: btw M.Deinum I did a quick test using unless="result.hasElements()" and that failed with org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1001E: Type conversion problem, cannot convert from reactor.core.publisher.MonoHasElements<java.lang.Boolean> to java.lang.Boolean
If I do something like: unless="False.equals(#result.hasElements().block())" that works, but I don't like the idea of blocking in the "unless" expression